# Removing Remote Locks from UNC Shared Paths

Tags: c#, filesystems, locking

I'm having trouble right now finding a solution for unlocking UNC path files for our deployment scenario.  Here is the current situation:

We have multiple file server machines.  Our deployment application is setup to deploy from an MSBUILD drop location to a set of target folders (Using defined filters, etc).  These file shares are used by many users of the company to run our software.  As these users open our software, they create a remote read lock on the files they use.

We have admin accounts to do this (via impersonation) of our deployer.  We can also do this manually via remote computer management.  The problem comes in when we try to automate the process in our autobuilds.

At our current state, we were trying to use openfiles.exe to read and unlock the files (via /query /s //server /v), parsing the IDs, then using the ID to remove the lock.  The problem we run into is that openfiles.exe returns local file paths vs UNC file paths.

Is there a way to remotely remove a file lock from a server only knowing that file's UNC path (and not knowing it's local path)?  We don't necessarly have permission to add applications on the target servers (as there are many), so solutions such as PsExec -> Handle.exe would most likely not work for us.

Thanks in advance for any help!
-Corey

Comment: Not answering your actual question - but this sounds like a quick descent into a world of pain: Replacing pieces of an application *while the application is running* is a very good way to create nasty nasty heisenbugs. In the same situation, I'd set up the applications to transparently deploy on activation from the network share to a local directory on the users machines. No file locks to defeat, no deployment problems for new versions, and no problems caused by half upgraded hybrid apps.

Comment: Thanks Bevan.  While normally I would agree with you, in this situation we don't care about breaking users.  The application is opened read only, and if it blows up we don't care specifically, as they'll just re-open the application (and there are DB redundancies that stop them entering bad data).

Though my preferred response would be to remove the share and remotely deploy (1/2 way there with our clickonce deployments!), it's still a good distance until that takes priority.

Comment: I don't know of a way to convert UNC paths to remote physical paths (which is what you essentially need) but can you just deploy to a unique folder name (YOUR_APP_1234 or something), search for that folder name using `openfiles`, boot everyone in that folder, obtain an exclusive lock on it, deploy and remove the lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can use WMI to query a Windows computer for a list of its defined shares, which would include the share name and the local path.

Given the strong integration of WMI into PowerShell - and given that PowerShell is *much* easier to use than raw WMI - it shouldn't be too difficult to write a powershell function that converts a UNC path into a local path for the host machine.

As a starting point, check out [PowerShell Scripting - WmiObject Win32_Share](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_wmi_shares_simple.htm):

> The purpose of this script is to list shares on a server.  In fact, this code will enumerate the shares on any computer.

If you get this working, please share the result!

Comment: I've never used powershell before, but it doesn't seem that bad to setup a file I can process with output redirect to read from inside the program.  I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: This works fine.  With the way that the program works, we can actually  just use WMI, using the .net System.Management wrapper classes to do the same queries.